# Как удалить из .txt спустя время с помощью PHP

Tags: php, datetime, sms, txt

У меня есть скрипт, который проверяет входящие данные от пользователя и сравнивает эти данные с данными из файла .txt и если они верны, очищает файл. Как сделать что бы данные очищались из файла, например спустя минуту после записи их в файл

ЗАПИСЬ В ФАЙЛ

```
`

$rnd = rand(100000, 999999);

    $i = 0;
    //  Открываем "file.txt" в режиме чтения
    $fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if ($fp) {
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $mytext = fgets($fp);
        $array[$i] = trim($mytext);
        $i++;
    }
    }
    fclose($fp);
     $key = array_search($phone, $array);
    // Запись номера и кода в файл
        if ($key === FALSE) {
    $filename = 'file.txt';
    $somecontent = "\n" . $phone . "\n" . $rnd . "\n" . date("H:i:s");
    if (is_writable($filename)) {
        if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
            exit;
        }
        // Записываем $somecontent в наш открытый файл.
        if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
            exit;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    //  Посылаем get-запрос на отправку кода подтверждения на введенный пользователем 
    номер
    $var = file_get_contents('https://auth.ru/outbox/send/?login=' . $user . 
   '&password=' . $pass . '&sender=' . $sourceAddress . '&target=' . $phone . '&message=' 
   . $rnd . '');
    echo json_encode('Код отправлен на' . ' ' . $phone);
    } else {
    echo json_encode('Уже был отправлен на' . ' ' . $phone);
    }


    die();
```

`

УДАЛЕНИЕ ИЗ ФАЙЛА ЕСЛИ ДАННЫЕ СОВПАДАЮТ ОТ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ

```
`

$codesms = $_POST["codesms"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];

    $i=0; 
    //  Открываем "file.txt" в режиме чтения
    $fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if ($fp){
        while (!feof($fp)){
            $mytext = fgets($fp);
            $array[$i]=trim($mytext);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $arr=$array;
    fclose($fp);
    $key = array_search($phone, $arr);
    $code=$arr[$key+1];
    $phoneex=$arr[$key];
    if ($code == $codesms && $phoneex==$phone){
        echo json_encode($code);
        //  Удаление номера с кодом из файла
        $file=file("file.txt");
        $fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($file);$i++){
            if($i==$key){
                unset($file[$i]);
                unset($file[$i+1]);
            }
        }
        fputs($fp,implode("",$file));
        fclose($fp);
    }else{
        echo json_encode("Неверный номер или код подтверждения") ;
    }
```

`

Comment: этот код будет периодически очищать файл целиком

Comment: какой код? На какой строке тут идет очищение файла?) Мне нужно реализовать, что бы он чистил именно определенную строку, что бы человек мог спустя например минуту, попобовать еща раз

Comment: тут везде идёт очищение файла. любая работа с файлом без блокировок приводит к очищению. Не надо колупаться с файлами вообще, возьмите sqlite. код станет в десять раз короче и в миллион раз надежнее

Comment: так у тебя нет определенной строки, у тебя данные одного юзера разбиты на несколько строк, почему не писать их в одну строку... или в формате csv.